# Why is Web::Scraper so slow?

Tags: perl

I'm using Web::Scraper to yank some data from a very simple table and convert it to my needs. I'm also using WWW::Mechanize to do the form submitting, which isn't slow at all.

Once I started using the Web::Scraper, I noticed takes a very long time to return the data from the page. Profiling shows the following:

```
6299228 13.7s   line    XML/XPathEngine/Step.pm
7335    10.9s   line    Net/HTTP/Methods.pm
3990690 10.4s   line    XML/XPathEngine/NodeSet.pm
2690467 7.72s   line    HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm
2047085 5.70s   line    XML/XPathEngine/Function.pm
978212  3.37s   line    XML/XPathEngine/Literal.pm
1791592 3.29s   line    HTML/Element.pm
661985  3.15s   line    XML/XPathEngine.pm
1997421 2.52s   line    XML/XPathEngine/Expr.pm
```

Running it on console yields the following:

```
real    0m28.042s
user    0m11.312s
sys     0m0.121s
```

Using a web browser form construction (debugging) I'm only seeing 3.5 seconds with a custom query, so I've narrowed it down to Web::Scraper taking the time.

Here's some of the web scraper code, ie:

```
$offers = scraper {
        process 'table> tr' => 'td[]' => scraper {
        process 'td.tdCallNumber > strong ' => 'tdCallNumber' => 'TEXT';
        process 'td.tdDateReceived >strong ' => 'tdDateReceived' => 'TEXT';
        process 'td.tdTimeReceived >strong' => 'tdTimeReceived' => 'TEXT';
        process 'td.tdLocation>strong'      => 'tdLocation'     => 'TEXT';
        process 'td.tdDesc>strong'          => 'tdDesc'         => 'TEXT';
        process 'td > table '               => 'table'          => 'TEXT';
        process 'td>table>tr' => 'data[]' => scraper {
            process 'td.tdUnit'    => 'tdUnit' => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdDIS' => 'tdDIS'  => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdENR' => 'tdENR'  => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdONS' => 'tdONS'  => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdLEF' => 'tdLEF'  => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdARR' => 'tdARR'  => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdBUS' => 'tdBUS'  => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdREM' => 'tdREM'  => 'TEXT',
                process 'td.tdCOM' => 'tdCOM'  => 'TEXT',
                ;
        };

    }
};
my $D;
my $print_header = 1;

$D = $offers->scrape($text);
```

...

Some more of it that converts it to html based output (almost identical table forms).

```
my $r;
for $r ( @{ $D->{td} || [] } ) {
    if ( $r->{tdCallNumber} ) {
        if ($print_header) {
            $npage .= "

$r->{tdCallNumber}, $r->{tdDateReceived}, $r->{tdTimeReceived},
            $r->{tdLocation}, $r->{tdDesc};
    }
    if ( $r->{data} ) {
        $npage .= '
```

Is there anything I can do to improve the speed?

Comment: Are you performing anything else within the code? Perhaps it would be better if you post a sample code that people can also look at and perhaps debug with you to see what may possible be the issue. Don't forget to measure the avg time from `you <> site` which can also imply on the slowness along with other things.

Comment: I added some of the code, and I'm not doing anything complex. Using WWW:Mechanize to login to the site, input data into a form, Using Web::Scaper to take the data and convert it into a local form.

Comment: I would check out selenium for web scraping needs.. its pretty awesome

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can take a look at [`HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3A%3ATreeBuilder%3A%3ALibXML). The module documentation talks about `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` being slow for large documents, and that is implements "enough methods ... so modules like Web::Scraper work". A benchmark on the documentation page shows that the libxml variant is about 1600% faster than the pure-perl variant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use NYTProf to find the exact slow place in your program or the libs. Once you see what is slow then you could improve it.

http://www.slideshare.net/Tim.Bunce/develnytprof-200907

```
# profile code and write database to ./nytprof.out
perl -d:NYTProf some_perl.pl

# convert database into a set of html files, e.g., ./nytprof/index.html
# and open a web browser on the nytprof/index.html file
nytprofhtml --open
```